# How to use the geometry package with newlfm documents?

Tags: margins, geometry, newlfm

I am using the newlfm letter documentclass, and try loading the geometry package. This returns the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \geometry already defined.
```

What I want to do is put more space (margin) between the text and the top of the page. A MWE is provided below:

```
\documentclass{newlfm}
\usepackage[margin=0mm, top=2mm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Recipient Company\\ Recipient Address}

\opening{Dear Sir or Madam,}

Here goes the letter content

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You could use the class' "geometry" commands.  They are detailed in the documentation.

Answer (score 10):

The command `\geometry`, it seems, is already defined by the class  `newflm`. If you do not want that default page setting put

```
\let\geometry\relax
```

just below `\documentclass{newlfm}`

Your file becomes:

```
\documentclass{newlfm}
\let\geometry\relax
\usepackage[margin=0mm, top=2mm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Recipient Company\\ Recipient Address}

\opening{Dear Sir or Madam,}

Here goes the letter content

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

**Update** Ignoring the commands defined by the document class will certainly cause trouble at some point of time (Agreeing with @Mico). Hence it is always better to use these commands. This MWE shows how to play with different margins using the built-in commands of the `newlfm` class itself.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{newlfm}
%% to change margins-----------------------
\leftmarginsize{0in}
\rightmarginsize{0in}
\topmarginsize{2mm}
\topmarginskip{0in}
\headermarginsize{0in}
\headermarginskip{0in}
%%-----------------------------------------
\usepackage{lipsum} %% to add dummy text
%%-----------------------------------------
\nameto{George Bush} \addrto{\parbox{2in}{The White House \\ Washington, DC}}
\namefrom{Paul Thompson} \addrfrom{\parbox{2in}{The Pink House \\ Belleville, IL}}
%%-----------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\closeline{Sincerely yours,} \greetto{Dear Mr. Bush,}
\begin{newlfm}
How are the azaleas?

\lipsum[5]
\end{newlfm}
\end{document}
```

For more details one may run `texdoc newlfm` from from the command prompt and the details of these lengths can be found in page 8 of the manual. I am attaching a screen shot of the same.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

(Too long for a comment)

From the user guide of the [newlfm](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/newlfm/) document class:

> `geometry` is no longer used for dimension setting. Rather, all dimensions are set internally. This is done using a combination of default values, header and footer sizes and values input from the user. These include primarily the page size commands `leftmarginsize`, `textwidthsize` and `rightmarginsize`.

I guess the implication of this passage is that if you're going to use this document class for letters, faxes, and memos, you should try *not* to use the `geometry` package and its methods; instead, try using the parameters provided by the `newlfm` document class directly. Conversely, even though you may be able load the `geometry` package after all -- see @HarishKumar's answer -- by first undefining the `\geometry` command, you may find that the page-related parameters won't work the way you might expect them to work in, say, the `article` document class.

*Addendum*: Here's a quick example of how you could proceed if you wanted the left and right margins to be 1.5" wide each:

```
\leftmarginsize{1.5in}
\rightmarginsize{1.5in}
```

The text block's width would then be calculated as `<paperwidth>-2*1.5"`; if the paper happens to be "US Letter"-size (8.5"x11"), the text block would end up being 5.5" wide. Other page-related parameters will, in general, be determined by the options you provide as arguments to the `\documentclass[...]{newlfm}` command.

Comment: Yes, I totally agree with your answer; perhaps you could include a little example of the ways to change the topmargin: `\topmarginskip{1in}` or `\newlfmP{topmarginskip=1in}`.